# BigQuery Syntax Change -- SELECT DISTINCT json_col no longer works?

Tags: json, google-bigquery, dbt

I have an hourly `dbt` job running. Last night, between 3am-4am, the job started failing and 9 files/models started producing errors.

My dbt workflow ingests JSON data from MongoDB and saves the output to Google BigQuery tables. Last night, suddenly, the code in these 9 files started producing the error:
Column of type JSON cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT.

My code in these 9 files takes on the form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, json_col3
…
```

There are many JSON type columns in my data and I only unnest some of them. This worked previously without issue in 9 files, for months. Now, there is a problem. Was there a change to Google BigQuery that no longer allows SELECT DISTINCT with JSON columns? I don’t see any mention of such a change in the release notes, nor any release notes for today.

Comment: In your problem statement you have indicated possible issue with BigQuery where as I believe you are executing the SELECT DISTINCT statement against MongoDB. Please confirm if I have understood that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same exact inquiry in Google Cloud Community, posting the [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/BigQuery-Syntax-Change-SELECT-DISTINCT-json-col-no-longer-works/m-p/667480) here for visibility.

This may also be related to the [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data#limitations) of a JSON data in GoogleSQL as it is the base language of BigQuery.

> You can't use legacy SQL to query a table that contains JSON types.